# How to destructure multiple values from the object?

Tags: javascript

I want to destructure the values from the same object inside multiple objects.

```
const data ={
  building1: {
    floor: 'cnt',
  }
  building2: {
    floor: 'bcnt'
  }
}
```

Is there any way to destructure in single line as `floor1, floor2`

Answer (score 5):

As simple as that:

```
const { building1: { floor: floor1 },building2: { floor: floor2 }} = data;
```